# How do I multisite with share user (and SSO), separate/dedicated users' role and content database on each site

Tags: 8, users, multi-sites

I like to make **Drupal 8** in CentOS 7 with Apache 2.4, mySQL and PHP 5.6 environment with requirements:

1. **Multi-site** within domain (site0.example.org, site1.example.org, etc.)
2. **Shared local user** account with **SSO** (userid, password, and all of user entities - name, email, address, phone, ...)
3. Different/**dedicated content** databases for each site
4. Different/**dedicated users' role** for each site

So, The user should be able to login in any sites and maintain the session across sites (SSO) but they may have different role, access and permission at different sites.

For example:

I'm login at site 1 (site1.example.org) and I have admin role in site so I can administer site 1.

But when I move to site 2 (site2.example.org) - I don't need to re-login again (**SSO**) but I may have a **different role** in site 2 (e.g authenticated user - view only).

What is the ***Best*** approach for this requirements?
Bakery? OpenLDAP? Saml? Or any other solutions?

Comment: The best approach is going to depend on your requirements. For instance, if you're working with a highly-integrated Windows environment, then LDAP probably is the way to go. However the only requirement/assumption here is "shared user globally". This probably means that bakery, OpenLDAP, CAS, etc... are not options because they do not share users globally, but maintain their own users table. Can you make your question more specific and less subjective?

Comment: Thank you for the reply and apologise if it looks subjective, i have edited the question hopefully it is more meaningful. Reaponding to your comment, the system is running on CentOS servers or none windows environment. The requirement is basically combination of: multisite within domain+shared local user(with SSO)+site dedicate content (different content DB) and users' role.